# Can't change property of self in asynchronous block

Tags: ios, asynchronous, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to change some properties of self, however I can't change it in my asynchronous block.
Here is my code:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

NSURLSessionDataTask *postTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (response == nil)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSString *markerName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"public-%@",[weakSelf.pad getMarkerNameForCategory:weakSelf.categoryLabel.text]];
            weakSelf.pad.markerName = markerName;

            [weakSelf.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        });
    }
}];

     [postTask resume];
}
```

If I'm setting a breakpoint after the assignment `weakSelf.pad.markerName = markerName` the markerName is not being set, it is still the old value.

Some project details: iOS 7, ARC enabled

**EDIT**

Changed the first line to `__block typeof(self) weakSelf = self;` but the problem still exists.

Comment: You're creating a `json` object, but not doing anything with it. Why?

Comment: @Abizern well skip that line...this is not the issue

Comment: Is it a case of the `markerName` variable not being set or the new value not showing in whatever your UI is?

Comment: @Abizern I set the breakpoint right after the assignment and the variable is not being set correctly

Comment: That doesn't sound right. How are you checking? Is the breakpoint on the `popViewController...` line?

Comment: I'm not even sure you need to use a weak version of `self` either, your class doesn't hold a strong reference to the block, so it's unlikely to create a retain cycle.

Comment: So at the breakpoint you `po` the values of `weakSelf.pad.markerName` and `markerName` and they are not the same?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.

Comment: Is this your __exact__ code? you haven't got any c/p errors in it? Are you sure that it's `weakSelf.pad.markerName = markerName;` and not `weakSelf.pad.markerName == markerName;`?

Comment: @Abizern this part is copied straight out of my project, so yes this is my exact code. I checked this already a hundred times, I know this is a really strange issue.

Comment: Have you verified that your property set method is functioning correctly?

Comment: Can you provide the declaration of your `pad` property ?

Comment: @AncAinu `Pad *createdPad = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Pad" inManagedObjectContext:context];` this pad is passed to my viewController, which has a `property (nonatomic, strong) Pad *pad`. The property is set in `prepareForSegue` and is correctly set in my viewController.